# How to remove hash symbol "#" in outline of markdown?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, outline

those symbols occupies the space of title and outline, and makes it looks confused.

I've tired may, but cannot find the xml file of vs. and no extension can help this.

Comment: Provide what you have now so we know what you are working with.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing that? hash symbols in the outline make you feel confident about all heading levels throughout your document. In this way, you can instantly see if there are broken headings. Imagine, you get rid of all of them. How do you expect to check the consistency of headings?

Comment: I also feel its annoying to have [abc] ### on every item of the outline. There is already a feature request about it, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/53992 maybe you can subscribe and up vote it.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this writing, you can't. But there's an open feature-request issue ticket for it: [Outline view + Markdown: Do not display the "#"s
#53992](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/53992). I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".