# In VS Code, how can I disable the default document outline provider for Markdown?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to implement a VS Code extension that generates a custom outline for a Markdown document by number-indexing its section, like `1. Heading`, `1.1. Subheading`, ... I managed to implement it below using the API command `vscode.languages.registerDocumentSymbolProvider` to register a custom `DocumentSymbolProvider`.

However, the default outline of Markdown, which starts with `#`, `##`, ... also appear in the outline view, like in the below screenshot.

How can I disable such a default outline view, and only display the ones starting with `1.` , `1.1.` , ...?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you'd need to just have the user completely disable their builtin Markdown Language Features extension (go to Extension View, search `@builtin markdown`). I'm not aware of a way for an extension to suppress symbols provided by another extension.

Or if you use a different symbol type than that of the symbol(s) you want to "suppress", you could tell your user to use a corresponding `"[<language mode>]": { "outline.show<symbo type>": false }` setting. Ex.

```json
"[markdown]": {
    "outline.showStrings": true,
},
```

FYI, see also [How to remove hash symbol "#" in outline of markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63570742/11107541).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I set `"outline.showStrings": false` and it can filter the strings `#...` from the outline panel. However, those strings still appear in the Go To Symbol dialog. Do you know how to hide them too?

Comment: @TrungTa no idea